# vuetify expansion-panels arrow image doesn't show

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]

I'm trying to use vuetify expansion-panels in Vue.js.

But you can see that arrow image doesn't show in this picture.

Even I tried to delete :expand-icon="images.arrow" it apears string "keyboard-arrow-down"

Here's my code.

Any ideas? thanks.

```
 images: {
          check: require('../assets/check.png'),
          uncheck: require('../assets/uncheck.png'),
          memo: require('../assets/memo.png'),
          thumbsUp: require('../assets/thumbs-up.svg'),
          chrome: require('../assets/chrome.svg'),
          arrow: require('../assets/arrow.svg'),
        },
      ...


      <v-expansion-panel>
        <v-expansion-panel-content :expand-icon="images.arrow" v-for="(item,i) in 5" :key="i">
          <div slot="header">Item</div>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
              labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
              aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: I have heard of people having difficulty with custom icons or custom svgs with vuetify. Basically the 'expand-icon' is expecting an icon font like material design or font awesome provide, not just an svg. So you can try creating your own which I couldn't tell you how to do or use one of theirs.

Comment: @Andrew1325 thanks. installing fontawesome is how I solved it.